# Encapsulate output with ' '

Tags: awk

Current Output:

```
'31123456787
31123456788
31123456789
```

Required Output:

```
'31123456787'
'31123456788'
'31123456789'
```

***Current code being used:***

```
variable=`awk -F, '{OFS=",";print $1,$2}' /app/isc/Test/archive/data/Final_Account_Status_Check.csv | tr -d ',' `
echo "'$variable'" >> /app/isc/Test/archive/data/Final_Account_Status_Check.txt
```

Comment: You're setting OFS to `,` in awk and then removing all `,`s using `tr`. **Think** about that for a second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***EDIT(Improve OP's attempt):*** After seeing OP's code trying to improve and do the task in single `awk` command itself by improving OP's code.

```
awk -v s1="'" 'BEGIN{FS=","} {print s1 $1,$2 s1}'  /app/isc/Test/archive/data/Final_Account_Status_Check.csv > /app/isc/Test/archive/data/Final_Account_Status_Check.txt
```

***Improvements done in OP's code:***

- Removed `OFS=","` and `tr` parts from OP's first command since later OP is removing them from `td` so it doesn't make sense to have it.
- Declare an `awk` variable `s1` whose value is `'` which we will add to output later.
- Added `s1` before `$1` and after `$2` to get output in `'bla bla bla'` form as per OP's requirement.

---

---

***Codes as per OP's ask:***

Could you please try following(this solution assumes that we need to read an Input_file to get OP's expected output).

```
awk -v s1="'" '{print s1 $0 s1}' Input_file
```

---

---

Since you have not shown complete requirement or samples of input or expected output so by seeing your attempts seems  you could be printing a variable's value and pass it to `awk` then.

```
echo "$your_variable" | awk -v s1="'" '{print s1 $0 s1}'
```

Comment: Those examples added the ' which is great, how would i get it to return each value onto a new line ?

Comment: @P.4001, IMHO, my EDIT code or my last code should work for you, kindly test it once and let me know then?

Answer (score 0):

So you want to add `'` to the beginning and ending of each line.

```
echo "$variable" | sed "s/^/'/; s/$/'/"
```